# Run certain function in bash script based off flag

Tags: bash

I have three separate bash scripts that send an email based on certain criteria in another script. What I would like to do is combine all those into one script and make them functions and use that in the main script but use flags to call the right function. So I have this code

```
main()
{

    while getopts "f:s:k:" opt; do
        case ${opt} in
            f) sendFirstEmail 
            ;;
            s) sendSecondEmail 
            ;;
            k) sendKillEmail 
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

main
```

I didn't put the actual functions in that piece of code for readability but those functions each take an argument:`$1`. So what I want is to be able to do this: `script.sh -f johndoe@mail.com`and have that send johndoe the first email. When I run this, the code does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the flag, which is a standard thing in scripting. You can use the Bash builtin `getopts` or the `case` construct. See `man bash` for details. I'd define all the functions first, then define a main funtion `main` and finally call it, passing it the flag(s).

You could also base the switch on the way the script is called and create differently named symbolic links to it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t passing the argument that accompanies your flag to the function. The variable that holds the value for the getopts flag is OPTARG.

```
main()
{

    while getopts "f:s:k:" opt; do
        case “${opt}” in
            f) sendFirstEmail “$OPTARG”
            ;;
            s) sendSecondEmail “$OPTARG”
            ;;
            k) sendKillEmail “$OPTARG”
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

main
```